# Loading spinner shown after task completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I working on spring boot project. I want to show spinner on my page. (lots of calculation on task) Page maybe shown 5 minutes later. Working on my spinner last 1 second. Because my page elements are not loading long time. My process are long actually. I want to spinner shows start of the process.

Comment: I search on google. Find solution like :
   .ajaxStart(function () {
                $loading.show();})

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax then you can use ajaxStart and ajaxStop method to display spinner on your screen like below.

```
<div id="loading">
    <img src="loader.gif" />  
</div>

<script>
   var $loading = $('#loading').hide();
   $(document)
     .ajaxStart(function () {
         $loading.show();
     })
   .ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but not working. I checked using console.log to  show and hide part but nothing appears.

Comment: you should also check network tab for on going requests and console for the errors if any

Answer (score 0):

If you show your code, it will be easier to understand what the error is.

Your task should be divided into several subtasks.

1. Make sure the request is successful
2. Print to the console the moment of the beginning of the request and the completion of the request
3. Next to the console output code, write an interface change handler (show or hide spinner)